# Returning an updated object

Tags: java

How do I return the updated rectangle from the BasicRect cut from the example I've provided?

Just getting an error for the `BasicRect` in the horizontal cut.

```
public class BasicRect implements ADT_BasicRect, Comparable<BasicRect> {

    private int x, y, h, w;

    public BasicRect(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        h = y;
        w = x;
    }

    public int getArea() {
        return h * w;
    }

    @Override
    public BasicRect horizontalCut(int c) {
        /**
         * Provided the cut-value is strictly between 0 and the width of this
         * BasicRect, the width of this is changed to the cut-value. The
         * BasicRect representing the right-hand part of the cut is returned.
         *
         * @param c the cut value
         * @return the right-hand part of the cut If the cut-value is not
         * strictly between 0 and the width of this, an IllegalArgumentException
         * is thrown
         */
        if(c > 0 && c < w){
            // make the cut
            x = x-w;
        }else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be smaller than"
                    + " width but larger than 0");
        }
        return BasicRect;
    }
```

EDIT

```
BasicRect br1 = new BasicRect(5, 9);
BasicRect br2 = new BasicRect(4, 5);

System.out.println(br1.compareTo(br2));

System.out.println(br1.getArea());
br1= br1.horizontalCut(3);
System.out.println(br1.getArea());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a object, update its properties and return it.

```
public BasicRect horizontalCut(int c) {
    BasicRect br = new BasicRect();
    br.x = x;
    br.y = y;
    br.h = h;
    br.w = w;
    if(c > 0 && c < w){
        // make the cut
        br.x = x-w;
    }else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be smaller than"
                + " width but larger than 0");
    }
    return br;
}
```

If you want to modify current object and return it, do so.

```
public BasicRect horizontalCut(int c) {
    if(c > 0 && c < w){
        // make the cut
        x = x-w;
    }else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be smaller than"
                + " width but larger than 0");
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: So theres no way to update the current object? Rather than having to create a new one?

Comment: Hi mate, is there a reason my update doesn't work? Just trying to test it (check my edit)

Comment: Also I believe its supposed to be x = x - c rather than - w, that was my mistake

Comment: What is "work"? It should compile and just moving the rect won't affect its area.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work on current object  as asked in below comment. I believe `BasicRect` is the domain object, created already in some service. So this is the way you need to go

```
public BasicRect horizontalCut(int c) {

    if(c > 0 && c < w){
        // make the cut
        this.x = this.x-w;
    }else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be smaller than"
                + " width but larger than 0");
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: `this.x = this.x-this.x;` seems like `this.x = 0;`

Comment: Thanks. Corrected typo mistake